# Custom Field as Name Field

Tags: api, custom-field, metadata

How do i set a custom field to be the name field of a particular custom object?

So far, I have created a custom object and while doing so I have create a namefield by using:

```
            <nameField>
                 <displayFormat>FIELD-{0000}</displayFormat>
                 <label>namefield__c</label>
                 <type>AutoNumber</type>
            </nameField>
```

Edit1:

```
<soapenv:Body>
<create xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<metadata xsi:type="ns2:CustomObject" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<fullName>nokia__c</fullName>
<deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>
<description>created by the Metadata API</description>
<enableActivities>true</enableActivities>
<label>Dummy</label>
<nameField>
<displayFormat>NOKIA-{0000}</displayFormat>
<label>permission_c</label>
<type>AutoNumber</type>
</nameField>
<pluralLabel>Nokia</pluralLabel>
<sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
<SearchLayouts>
<customTabListAdditionalFields>test__c</customTabListAdditionalFields>
</SearchLayouts>
</metadata>
</create>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't. The name field for any custom object will have the API name of Name, and for most standard objects, it will also be Name, with a few special exceptions, like Cases. You can only affect its data type (auto-number or text), its label, and its display format, when using auto-number.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0caiczawrv94rd/Screenshot%20from%202017-01-23%2023%3A35%3A58.png?dl=0      With reference to this screenshot, can i atleast create another column through which i push unique data into each of that column to make them unique as in a "Name" column in lead fields

Comment: @MohanKrishnan You can create a text field with the External Id attribute selected (and optionally Unique). This would let you specify your own API name, and you can use the upsert method against this field to insert/update records.

Comment: ok. Will give it a try.

Comment: I studied external ids but couldnt get the desired output. To make things clear, I have atteached a screenshot which specifies my need. Pls take a look into it, and instruct me in the right direction. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1icg5nxhxq3c5wp/BeFunky%20Collage.jpg?dl=0    So I need to create a column link 'Company' which populates from a custom field inside the object

Comment: @MohanKrishnan You can edit the various layouts in your custom object under Search Layouts.

Comment: i h have edited my question with the xml deployed used. Could get success response, but no column created on layout?. Forgive me asking for too many questions, I have been on this for 5-6 hrs, without any success. :(

Comment: @MohanKrishnan XML is case-sensitive: it should be `searchLayouts`. See [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_searchlayouts.htm)

Comment: tried "searchLayouts", still no column. My Hunch is, I create custom object and then custom tab and then custom field (in this order). Hence while creating custom object itself, I have to specify the custom field for the  'customTabListAdditionalFields' param, at that time the custom field wasnt created. Any suggesstions on this??

Comment: @MohanKrishnan I presume you're using the CRUD-based API? If you deployed using the file-based API, you could do it all at once. The tab isn't necessary for the field though, but yes, the CRUD-based API would need three separate commands minimum.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the name field is a standard field (API name = name). Any custom field you'll create will have the "__c" extension. So there is no way you can really override the name field.

Having said that, why don't you simply edit the standard name field and change it to be an auto-number?

[image: Object creation]

[image: Name field auto-number]